# response.write() will not accept a string. It acts as though it is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have passed the postData object from a `response.on('data'...` and all is well so long as I am working with `console.log()`. However when I try to us `postData.toString()` or pass it to `response.write()` it is treated as undefined. I am so confused by this behavior.

```
upload = function(response, postData) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    console.log(postData); // outputs the data that was posted
    console.log(typeof postData); // outputs string
    var item = postData; // successfully sets item equal to postData
    console.log(item); // outputs the data as expected
    console.log(typeof item); // outputs string
    response.write('You\'ve sent: ' + item); //writes "You've sent: undefined"
    response.end();
}
```

My full code is at: [Node.js request data event not firing. What am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599263/node-js-request-data-event-not-firing-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

I don't know if I am causing a problem, or using deprecated methods or what. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like `postData` is the *string* "undefined".  Check the call to your `upload` function.  Use the [inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) to set a breakpoint and see what's happening.

Comment: where is the function `upload` being used?  Typically form data is not a string, but rather an object that needs to be parsed (since it can contain all sorts of crazy things).  You may want to use at least check out the npm module formidable (https://www.npmjs.org/package/formidable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be [within the `createServer()` callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599263/node-js-request-data-event-not-firing-what-am-i-doing-wrong), which is attempting to `route()` each `request` and `response` twice -- once without `postData`, once with:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    // ...

    // routes to `upload()` without a 4th argument
    // so, `postData` will be `undefined`
    route(handle, pathname, response);

    // ...

    request.on('end', function(postDataChunk) {
        // ...

        // routes to `upload()` again, this time with `postData`
        route(handle, pathname, response, postData);
    });
}).listen(portToUse);
```

Since each call to `route()`, and in turn `upload()`, is trying to `write()` and `end()` the `response`, only the 1st of the 2 will actually be able to `write()` anything.

This is because `response.write()` can't do anything after `response.end()` is called and closes the `net.Socket` behind the `response`.

However, `console.log()` doesn't have this dependency, so you should be seeing logs for both calls:

```
undefined          // from: console.log(postData)
'undefined'        // from: console.log(typeof postData)
undefined          // from: console.log(item)
'undefined'        // from: console.log(typeof item)
foo=bar&baz=qux    // from: console.log(postData)
'string'           // from: console.log(typeof postData)
foo=bar&baz=qux    // from: console.log(item)
'string'           // from: console.log(typeof item)
```

Comment: Thank you. That is what I needed. I removed the route() without the fourth argument, and it worked as I meant it to. Thanks so much.